# Accesing ReleaseFolderFactory in ALM using Java, Com4j

Tags: java, api, alm, ota, com4j

I have connected HP ALM 12.5 with Java through wrapper class via Com4j. To get release and cycle details, I need to access ReleaseFolderFactory object. Could you please help me to find the way using Java? Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can obtain ReleaseFolderFactory object from the connection object, using `ITDConnection3.releaseFolderFactory()` method:

```
ITDConnection3 conn = ....
IReleaseFolderFactory releaseFolderFactory = 
conn.releaseFolderFactory().queryInterface(IReleaseFolderFactory.class);
```